# x86 assembly - GetStdHandle & WriteConsole

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

In response to my question about Windows API's, I have successfully gotten it to work. My question is in regards to this code:

```
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    push NULL
    push offset other
    push mlen
    push offset msg
    push eax
    call WriteConsole
push    0
call ExitProcess
```

This code is supposed to print the value of `msg`. Why does one need to do:

a)

```
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    push NULL
```

And:

b)

```
push offset other
    push mlen
    push offset msg
    push eax
```

I am just wondering what the need is for getting a `StdHandle` and pushing offsets.

Thanks in advance,

Progrmr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [definition of WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The NULL is the last argument of the function, the lpReserved argument.  Arguments are pushed in right-to-left order.  The first function argument is the console handle, the one you got from GetStdHandle and you pass by pushing eax.

So properly commenting the assembly code:

```
push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          ; GetStdHandle nStdHandle argument
call GetStdHandle               ; eax = Console handle
push NULL                       ; lpReserved = null
push offset other               ; lpNumberOfCharsWritten = pointer to "other"
push mlen                       ; nNumberOfCharsToWrite = length of "msg"
push offset msg                 ; lpBuffer = pointer to "msg"
push eax                        ; hConsoleOutput = console handle from GetStdHandle
call WriteConsole               ; Write string
push    0                       ; exit code = 0
call ExitProcess                ; terminate program
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, where did you learn assembly (I just want to know a good place to learn)?

Comment: A self-built Z80 without an assembler, typing in the hex codes by hand.  Not exactly relevant for learning these days.  Nor is writing Windows code in assembler btw.