# How to make a system call in Windows with the IRC code?

Tags: assembly

Good by what I know system call and an API between the user and the kernel, so they are like functions correct?.

Good on Linux we have the system calls passing the syscall code (I think it's IRC?)
and calling the switch.

How would I do this in Windows 7 SP1? For example, how do I get the WriteConsoleA code to pass to EAX? What would be the switch of Windows?

Comment: On Windows you are supposed to call into kernel32.dll. Nothing else is guaranteed to work.

Comment: How about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665013/2189500

Comment: Most APIs are not implemented in the kernel.